# Actualizar base de datos desde View en MVC asp.net Core 2.0

Tags: mvc, linq, listview, controller, asp.net-core

Espero poder expresarme claramente y poder conseguir alguna ayuda.

Me tiene trabado la actualización de algunos campos en mi tabla de la base de datos desde el View. Actualmente lo pude hacer funcionar pero solo actualiza los datos del primer resultado.

¿Como debería funcionar? Se ingresan órdenes de pagos a clientes que van cancelando una deuda. Filtro la tabla para mostrar las órdenes de pago que ingresaron en el mes y tengo que actualizar los campos de `FechaLiq (datetime)`  y `Liquidada (bool)`.

Uso VS 2017 y asp.net Core 2.0.

Lei en varios post que el problema viene por el uso del `foreach` pero no supe como adaptar mi código a lo que plantean [acá](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30401500/update-multiple-records-at-once-in-asp-net-mvc)

Dejo partes del código.

**Controlador**

```
[HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<IActionResult> LiquidaOpj(int? NroOrden)
    {
        if (NroOrden == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        var opjToUpdate = await _context.Opj.SingleOrDefaultAsync(o => o.NroOrden == NroOrden);

        if (await TryUpdateModelAsync<Opj>(
            opjToUpdate,
            "",
            o => o.NroOrden,
            o => o.Liquidada,
            o => o.FechaLiq))
        {
            try
            {
                await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
                return View("Success");
            }
            catch (DbUpdateException)
            {
                //Log the error (uncomment ex variable name and write a log.
                ModelState.AddModelError("", "Fallo al guardar los cambios. " +
                    "Intente nuevamente, si el error sigue " +
                    "comuníquese con el administrador.");
            }
            return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
        }
        return View(opjToUpdate);
    }
```

**View** (primero el form para búsqueda)

```
<div class="col-md-6">
    <h4>Busqueda</h4>
    <hr />
    <form method="get">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label>Fecha Desde:</label>
            <input class="form-control input-sm" name="desde" type="date" />
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label>Fecha Hasta:</label>
            <input class="form-control input-sm" name="hasta" type="date" />
        </div>
        <input type="submit" asp-action="Index" class="btn btn-info btn-sm" value="Buscar" />
    </form>                
</div>
```

(form para mostrar resultados con el submit)

```
 <form asp-action="LiquidaOpj">
        <table class="table">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>
                        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Presentacion)
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.NroOrden)
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Caratula)
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.DNI)
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Liquidada)
                    </th>
                    <th></th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>

                @foreach (var item in Model)
                {
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Presentacion)
                            <input name="FechaLiq" type="hidden" value="@item.Presentacion" />
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.NroOrden)
                            <input name="NroOrden" type="hidden" value="@item.NroOrden" />
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Caratula)
                            <input name="Caratula" type="hidden" value="@item.Caratula" />
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.DNI)
                            <input name="Dni" type="hidden" value="@item.DNI" />
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Liquidada)
                            <input name="Liquidada" type="hidden" value="true" style="display:none" checked="checked">
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <a asp-action="Details" asp-controller="Opjs" asp-route-id="@item.NroOrden">Detalle</a>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                }
            </tbody>
        </table>
        <div class="form-group">
            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-sm" value="Generar" />
        </div>
    </form>
```

Como verán agregue `<input type="hidden"/>` para enviar al controlador los datos a actualizar.

Cualquier ayuda será bienvenidad.

Muchas gracias por leer.

Comment: por lo que veo estas mandando un arreglo con NroOrden y en el metodo solo recibes un elemento por lo que solo te recibira el  primer dato de ese arreglo lo que deberias hacer es mostrar el check y   en el metodo recibir un arreglo con los ids de las ordenes que vas a cancelar algo como  int[] Liquidada  y ya que todos los que marques con el check entraran en el metodo

Comment: y entonces dentro del metodo si tendrias que poner un foreach para recorrer ese arreglo y actualizar los datos de esas ordenes

Comment: Gracias, probaré lo que me recomiendas

Comment: @Xique, intenté pero no puedo avanzar. Si me pudieras pasar un código modelo para que pueda tener de referencia sería lo ideal ya que esto lo hago sin tener muchos conocimientos y estoy aprendiendo.

Comment: ok deja la agrego

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Xique lo pude hacer. Hice cambios en el View y también en el controlador. Publico para quien alguna vez tenga un situación similiar o mi respuesta sirva de ejemplo:

En el View agregue:

```
@for (int i = 0; i < Model.Count; i++)
   { 
     <td>@Html.HiddenFor(model => model[i].NroOrden)</td>
   }
```

Esto lo agregue para que pase un `name` de NroOrden diferente para cada uno de los resultados. De acuerdo al comentario del [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30401500/update-multiple-records-at-once-in-asp-net-mvc)

> Your first problem is that you use of a foreach loop is generating duplicate name attributes which will not bind to a collection and as a result the BillLists parameter will always be an empty collection (its also generating duplicate id attributes which is invalid html)

Y en el controlador hice un `foreach` para que tome cada uno del listado y actualice los campos requeridos

**Controlador**

```
[HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<IActionResult> LiquidaOpj(List<Opj> list, string FechaLiq)
    {
        var fecha = Convert.ToDateTime(FechaLiq);

        if(ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            foreach (var item in list)
            {
                var actualiza = await _context.Opj.Where(o => o.NroOrden.Equals(item.NroOrden)).FirstOrDefaultAsync();

                if (actualiza != null)
                {
                    actualiza.NroOrden = item.NroOrden;
                    actualiza.Liquidada = true;
                    actualiza.FechaLiq = fecha;
                }
            }
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
            return View("Success");
        }

        return View("AlgoNoEstaBien");

    }
```

En este caso el campo `FechaLiq` es el mismo valor de otro campo que tiene la tabla por eso pongo el mismo. Y el campo `Liquidada` le pongo `true`.

SIEMPRE se van a liquidar las Opj que estan dentro del mes que se filtra.

Espero que me haya podido explicar y gracias por todo.
Saludos

Answer (score 0):

ok lo primero que tenemos es la vista  entonces lo enviaremos mediante los checkbox que estén seleccionados entonces quedaría así

```html
 <form asp-action="LiquidaOpj">
        <table class="table">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>
                        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Presentacion)
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.NroOrden)
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Caratula)
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.DNI)
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Liquidada)
                    </th>
                    <th></th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>

                @foreach (var item in Model)
                {
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Presentacion)
                            <input name="FechaLiq" type="hidden" value="@item.Presentacion" />
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.NroOrden)
                            <input name="NroOrden" type="hidden" value="@item.NroOrden" />
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Caratula)
                            <input name="Caratula" type="hidden" value="@item.Caratula" />
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.DNI)
                            <input name="Dni" type="hidden" value="@item.DNI" />
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Liquidada)
                            <input name="Orden_Liquidar" type="hidden" value="@item.Orden_Id" >
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <a asp-action="Details" asp-controller="Opjs" asp-route-id="@item.NroOrden">Detalle</a>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                }
            </tbody>
        </table>
        <div class="form-group">
            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-sm" value="Generar" />
        </div>
    </form>
```

si te fijas lo único que hice fue des habilitar el checkbox y mostrarlo, para que cuando los envíes solo se van  a enviar los checkbox seleccionados en un arreglo: quite estas dos propiedades  `style="display:none" checked="checked"`
y cambie el nombre de Liquidada a Orden_Liquidar.

En el método  `LiquidaOpj` :

```html
[HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<IActionResult>LiquidaOpj(int[] Orden_Liquidar)
    {
        if (Orden_Liquidar.Length == 0)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }
        foreach(var Item in Orden_Liquidar)
        {
        var opjToUpdate = await _context
        .Opj.SingleOrDefaultAsync(o => o.NroOrden == item);
        //aqui actualizas el elemento con tu codigo y lo almacenas
        }
        //guardamos cambios 
        try{
                await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
                return View("Success");
        }
        catch (DbUpdateException)
        {
        //Log the error (uncomment ex variable name and write a log.
        ModelState.AddModelError("", "Fallo al guardar los cambios. " +
                    "Intente nuevamente, si el error sigue " +
                    "comuníquese con el administrador.");
        }
        return View();
    }
```

Lo primero que hacemos es checar si el arreglo no viene vació, eso ya lo validaras con JS en tu vista despues de esto recorremos cada uno de los elementos del mismo con un foreach, ya dentro del foreach buscamos el elemento 
con el id que trae el arreglo  y ya con eso puedes actualizar los datos.

Comment: Gracias nuevamente por responder. Probe tu código pero no me funciona. Al hacer click en generar me manda a una vista que no tengo (coincide con el nombre del método y el controlador:  `LiquidacionOPJ/LiquidaOpj`. Me surgen dos dudas: 1) vi que agregas un valor `value="@item.**Orden_Id**"` pero no es una propiedad que tengo en mi modelo. Y 2) en el mismo ejemplo del View aparace `type=hidden` y me comentabas que lo mostrabas para que uno pueda seleccionar. Aún así mostrandolo y cambiando el value y agregando la propiedad `Orden_Id`, no se actualizan los registros `NroOrden`

Comment: value="@item.**Orden_Id**" esa es el id de la orden no se como tengas ese atributo de tu modelo por eso lo puse as i

Comment: la idea es esa ya tu cambias los valores con los de tu proyecto

Comment: Si, por supuesto eso hice, pero por alguna razón no esta actualizando. Seguiré intentando. Si no avanzaré en otras cosas y después volveré a esto. Muchas gracias por tu ayuda.

Comment: en especifico que es lo que no funciona ??

Comment: No actualiza ningún registro y me al hacer click en el botón me lleva al siguiente View `LiquidacionOPJ/LiquidaOpj`